# Calculating download speed using time and size

Tags: python, ftp, file-transfer

How would I go about getting the average speed (in KBps and kbps) of a file being downloaded, using the size of the file and the time taken to download the file (in seconds?).

I also then need to take an average speed (in KBps and kbps) of 5 transfers.

This is what I have, I'm not sure if it is even the right start?

```
start_time = time.time()
ftp.storbinary('STOR stor.zip', file, 1024, uploadTracker.handle)
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
totalSizeInKiloBytes = totalSize / 1024
print "\n KB/PS: ", totalSizeInKiloBytes / elapsed_time
```

Thanks

Edit:
This is the output;

```
Progress: 100% [\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\]  50.00 kB/s
 Elapsed Time: 8.30499982834

 Size in Bytes: 52428800

 KB/PS:  6164.96099438
```

The KB/PS output seems wrong? How can it be 6164 when the speed at the end of hte progress bar never went above ~100 kB/s

Edit:

FtpUploadTracker class

```
class FtpUploadTracker:
    sizeWritten = 0
    totalSize = 0
    lastShownPercent = 1
    percentComplete = 0
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, totalSize):
        self.totalSize = totalSize
        self.count = 0

    def handle(self, block):
        self.sizeWritten += 1024
        self.percentComplete = round((self.sizeWritten / self.totalSize) * 100)
        if(self.percentComplete == 100):
            self.count = 1501

        if(self.count >= 1500): #count acts as a timer to only update percent complete text every ~1.5 seconds
            if (self.lastShownPercent != self.percentComplete):
                self.lastShownPercent = self.percentComplete
                pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=100)
                pbar.start()
                pbar.update(self.percentComplete)
                self.count = 0
        else:
            self.count += 1
```

Comment: I assume totalSize is defined elsewhere, and represents the file size in Bytes? Your calculation for KB/s is correct, but you should be aware that if you divide two integers, you will get an integer result (rounded down). If that's not what you want, make sure that at least one of the operands is a float. i.e. `totalSizeInKiloBytes / float(elapsed_time)`,  `totalSize / 1024.0`

Comment: Yes totalSize is the file size in Bytes. Are you sure it is correct? see my modified question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `uploadTracker.handle` calculates correctly ?

Comment: Updated the question with the uploadTracker class. I would assume it is calculating correctly!

Comment: You sent 52428800 Bytes = 51,200KB in 8.3s, so 6165KB/s sounds about right. Interestingly, that equates to approximately 50,000 *kilobits* per second. I'm with furas, `uploadTracker` has a problem with its units somewhere